# Testing throw with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, integration-testing

I have the following function to test:

```
export const createContext = async (context: any) => {
  const authContext = await AuthGQL(context)
  console.log(authContext)
  if(authContext.isAuth === false) throw 'UNAUTHORIZED'
  return authContext
}
```

I am trying to test the above function via:

```
describe('Testing Apollo service file', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await mongoConnect()
  })

  test('test apollo context setup and configuration', () => {
    const mockContext = {
      req: {
        headers: {
          
        }        
      }

    } as ExpressContext

    expect(() => createContext(mockContext)).toThrow()
  })

  afterAll(async () => {
    await mongoDisconnect()
  })
})
```

where my `beforeAll` `afterAll` calls are just connecting/disconnecting from the local database that will be used for data purposes.  I am passing in `mockContext` which normally will have more to it but for the sake of testing is fine and intentionally has missing fields to ensure the `createContext` throws 'UNAUTHORIZED'

Here is the terminal output for the test:

[image: Test output]

**UPDATED**

Per Jest documentation and doing more testing: https://jestjs.io/docs/using-matchers I wrote another function that throws an error and tested via the following line:

```
// test sync function
function compileAndroidCode() {
  throw new Error('UNAUTHORIZED');
}

// Expect function that tests the thrown error
expect(() => compileAndroidCode()).toThrow('UNAUTHORIZED')
```

So I seem to be messing something up in the async/await syntax with the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `async` function, so you need to `await` it. Try it like this:

```js
  test('test apollo context setup and configuration',async  () => {
    const mockContext = {
      req: {
        headers: {
          
        }        
      }

    } as ExpressContext

   await expect(createContext(mockContext)).rejects.toThrow()
  })
```

Comment: Changed to the above and still fails saying "Received function did not throw"

Comment: I've updated my answer, `expect` should call the function immediately.

Comment: thank you for this.  Updated answer ended up being correct.  In case anyone comes across this and wants the official docs as well, here they are: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous